# Yii2: auto fill fields based on another field from related table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii2

I have a MySQL table and model `patient_entry` which contains fields `patient_name`, `city` and `state`. I also have another table/model `health_card` which also contains `patient_name`, `city` and `state`.

Suppose the `patient_entry` table is already filled with `patient_name`, `city` and `state`.

When I am entering data in `health_card` form, when I select the `patient_name` via drop-down field related to `patient_entry` table, I want the related `city` and `state` fields to be auto-filled.

My `_form.php` for `health_card` looks like this:

```
    <head>
<script>

        $this->registerJs("$('#healthcard-patient_name').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '".yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("HealthCard/patient")."',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: $(this).val()},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#healthcard-city').val(data.city);
            $('#healthcard-pincode').val(data.pin);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('loading!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request');
        }
    });
});"); 

      </script>
</head>
```

And in the controller I have added, as per the suggestion, this:

```
public function actionPatient($id){
    // you may need to check whether the entered ID is valid or not
    $model= \app\models\PatientEntry::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        'city'=>$model->disrict_city,
        'pin'=>$model->pin_code
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is calling an `AJAX` request to get needed fields. Just act like below:

1. (I do not know your model name)take a look at your form and see what is the `id` of your `patient_name` field. It is usually `modelname-fieldname`. I assume that your model name is `Patient`. So, the id of `patient_name` would be `patient-patient_name`.
2. Add an ajax request (in your view).

The code for calling AJAX could look just like below:

```
$this->registerJs("$('#patient-patient_name').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '".yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("controllerName/patient")."',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: $(this).val()},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#patient-city').val(data.city);
            $('#patient-state').val(data.state);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('loading!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request');
        }
    });
});");
```

Notes:

- Change the **ControllerName** in above code with your own.
- I assumed that the id of `city` and `state` fields has the following id(s): `patient-city` and `state-city` relatively.
- **patient** is an action in your controller
- You may need to remove alerts|logs and do some customization on above code
- I didn't consider any conditions for code cleaning. Please make sure that user data is correct.

  3. Finally, add action code into your controller.

Action code:

```
public function actionPatient($id){
    // you may need to check whether the entered ID is valid or not
    $model=  \app\models\Patient::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        'city'=>$model->city,
        'state'=>$model->state
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Dear Ali, Thank you so much. Just a little clarification - for example my controller name is `HealthCardController` so should I write `HealthCardController/patient` or just `HealthCard/patient` and the code for view should go in head section under script tag.

Comment: You're welcome dear. This is correct: `healthCard/patient`. And about script tag, there is no need to put it into script tag. When you say `$this->registerJs`, Yii will automatically put that into `<script>` tag.

Comment: Dear Ali I have edited the question as per ur suggestion, but It looks like I am still missing something.

Comment: Dear If I am moving it outside of script tag, the code is displaying on view on the front. should it be after the opening php tag. 
No No-errors.

Comment: Hi Ali, I am trying to use a little modified version of this auto-fill. I have created a html text-field for input(general_regn_no) there is a field with the same name in another model. This is working well.
I have also placed a button beside the text-field and I want the search to be activated on clicking this button.

How I can modify this line to make it work for click on button event:
`$this->registerJs("$('#patient-patient_name').on('change',function()`

Comment: Dear Ali, I have made the changes as per ur suggestion, but I am getting `error in AJAX request` exact changes like this - `$this->registerJs("$('#general_regn_button').on('click',function()`

Comment: Hi Ali, If I am changing the code back to `$this->registerJs("$('#general_regn_number').on('change',function()` - it is working well, if I am using the field id. What I am missing here?