# yii2 autofill related field based on another field

Tags: yii2, autofill

I've a field called `employee_name` and depending on this field value I want to autofill another field `employee_id`. I've searched and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212029/yii2-auto-fill-fields-based-on-another-field-from-related-table) answer and tried implementing this on my form but I'm getting `Error in ajax request`. The jquery code in my form is

```
$('#emp').focusout(function() {
        empName = this.value;
        if ( empName != '' || empName != null ) {
            $('#depcustomer-employee_name').val(empName);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '".yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("deposit/employeeid")."',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {name: $(this).val()},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#depcustomer-employee_id').val(data.id);
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                alert('loading!');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('An error occured!');
                alert('Error in ajax request');
            }
        });
    });
```

My Controller name is `Deposit` and my controller code is

```
public function actionEmployeeid($name){
$model= app\modules\settings\models\DepEmployee::findOne(['employee_name'=>$name]);
return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
    'id'=>$model->employee_id
]);
```

What could be the possible reason that my ajax code is not working?

My form is quite big. Here's the part of the employee field entry

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">               
                 <?= $form->field($model, 'employee_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-6">  
                    <label for='emp'>Employee Name</label>
                    <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'employee_name')?>

                    <?php
                        echo AutoComplete::widget([
                            'name' => 'employee_name',
                            'id' => 'emp',
                            'clientOptions' => [
                                'source' => $dataEmp,
                                'autoFill'=>true,
                                'minLength'=>'2',
                                'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                                    $('#depcustomer-name').val(ui.item.id);
                                }")
                            ],
                         ]);
                    ?>      
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: How do you expect jquery to know this: `yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("deposit/employeeid")`?  Post your form to get more help please.

Comment: @stfsngue So, should I replace it with the absolute url like `http://localhost/testingDeposit/backend/web/index.php?r=deposit%2Fdeposit%2Femployeeid`

Comment: Try this answer down.

Comment: show `$dataEmp` content.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Here  `<?php
       $dataEmp = DepEmployee::find()
       ->select(['employee_name as value', 'employee_name as label','employee_id as id'])
       ->asArray()
       ->all();
       ?>`

Comment: @InsaneSkull Here's the generated html `<input id="emp" class="ui-autocomplete-input form-control" name="employee_name" autocomplete="off" type="text">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your autocomplete data you already have `employee_id`. So no need to make ajax request to get employee id.

**DepEmployee Model**

```
public static function getEmpData()
{
    $dataEmp = DepEmployee::find()
       ->select(['employee_name as value', 'employee_name as label','employee_id as id'])
       ->asArray()
       ->all();

    return $dataEmp;
}
```

**_form**

```
<?= AutoComplete::widget([
         'name' => 'employee_name',
         'id' => 'emp',
         'clientOptions' => [
              'source' => DepEmployee::getEmpData(),
              'autoFill'=>true,
              'minLength'=>'2',
               'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                   $('#depcustomer-name').val(ui.item.id);
                   $('#depcustomer-employee_id').val(ui.item.id);
               }")
          ],
]);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What i should do if i was at your place:

Here the view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'employeeName')->textInput([
    // I use onfocusout instead of focusout
    'onfocusout' => '
        $.post("generateemployeeid?name="+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#employee_id_container").html(data);
        });
    ',
]) ?>

<div id="employee_id_container"></div> // <- I will autofill here
```

Now here is the function who will fill the ID input: (should be in your controller)

```
public function actionGenerateemployeeid($name) {
    $employeeModel = DepEmployee::find()
        ->where(['employee_name' => $name])
        ->one();

    if($employeeModel !== NULL) {  
        echo  'Employee ID: <input type="text" name="EmployeeID" value="'.$employeeModel->employee_id.'" readonly><br>';
    }
    else {
        // error 404
    }
}
```

**Resume:** the jquery function take the employee name and send to the controller who will look for the employee ID in the database. Then send an input text with default value (employee ID) as response and load this input in the form.