# how to automatically enter data from form one to another form yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, autofill

I have a MySQL table and model `resume` which contains fields

```
'resume_id', 'lao', 'persen', 'eom', 'tgt_perpetugas' and 'tgt_pergeseran'
```

I also have another table/model `resumes` which also contains

```
'resumes_id', 'lao', 'persen', 'eom', 'tgt_perpetugas' and 'tgt_pergeseran'
```

Suppose the `resume` table is already filled with

```
'resume_id', 'lao', 'persen', 'eom', 'tgt_perpetugas','tgt_pergeseran'
```

When I am entering data in `resumes` form, when I select the `'lao'` via drop-down field related to `resume` table, I want the related

`'persen', 'eom', 'tgt_perpetugas' and 'tgt_pergeseran'`

fields to be auto-filled. my [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212029/yii2-auto-fill-fields-based-on-another-field-from-related-table) but 'Error in ajax request'. how to automatically enter data from form one to another form yii2
how to fix the error or is there a recommendation?

My _form.php for 'resumes' looks like this

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Resume;

    $routeAjax = \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("resume/resumes");

$js=<<<JS
function getRelatedFields(lao_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: '$routeAjax',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: lao_id},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             $('#resumes-persen').val(data.persen);
             $('#resumes-eom').val(data.eom);
             $('#resumes-tgt_perpetugas').val(data.tgt_perpetugas);
             $('#resumes-tgt_pergeseran').val(data.tgt_pergeseran);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('loading!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request'+textStatus'\n'+errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY); 


?>

<div class="resumes-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'lao')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Resume::find()->all(),'lao','lao'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih LAO'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents'=>[
        'select2:select' => 'function(e){getRelatedFields(e.params.data.id);}',
    ]
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'persen')->textInput(['type' => 'number','maxlength' => true, 'readOnly'=>false])->label('Perpetugas %') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'eom')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label('EOM') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tgt_perpetugas')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'readOnly'=>true])->label('Target Perpetugas') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tgt_pergeseran')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'readOnly'=>true])->label('Target Pergeseran') ?>

    <center>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    </center>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

And in the ResumesController,I have added. this:

```
public function actionResumes($id){
    // you may need to check whether the entered ID is valid or not
    $model =  \app\models\Resume::findOne(['lao'=>$id]);
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
            'eom'=>$model->eom,
            'persen'=>$model->persen,
            'tgt_pergeseran'=>$model->tgt_pergeseran,
            'tgt_perpetugas'=>$model->tgt_perpetugas
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want the fields

`'persen', 'eom', 'tgt_perpetugas', 'tgt_pergeseran'`

against the `lao` saved in the `Resume` model matching the dropdown() in the `Resumes` form `lao` field.

If that is correct then first you need to use the `Select2` event `select2:select`rather than using the traditional `onchange` event. Make a few changes to your `Select2` and the script on top of the view.

Replace your select2 with the following

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'lao')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Lao::find()->all(),'lao_id','lao_id'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih LAO'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents'=>[
        'select2:select' => 'function(e){getRelatedFields(e.params.data.id);}',
    ]
]); ?>
```

Replace the script on top of the view with the following

```
$routeAjax = \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("resume/resumes");

$js=<<<JS
function getRelatedFields(lao_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: '$routeAjax',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: lao_id},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             $('#resumes-persen').val(data.persen);
             $('#resumes-eom').val(data.eom);
             $('#resumes-tgt_perpetugas').val(data.tgt_perpetugas);
             $('#resumes-tgt_pergeseran').val(data.tgt_pergeseran);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('loading!');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request'+textStatus'\n'+errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Then you want to populate the similar fields from the **`Resume`** model to the **`Resumes`** `ActiveForm` when you select any option in the `lao` dropdown. You should be fetching the lao in the `Resume` model not `id` in the `Resumes` model.

So replace your action with the below

```
public function actionResumes($id)
{
    // you may need to check whether the entered ID is valid or not
    $model = \app\models\Resume::findOne(['lao' => $id]);
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        'eom' => $model->eom,
        'persen' => $model->persen,
        'tgt_pergeseran' => $model->tgt_pergeseran,
        'tgt_perpetugas' => $model->tgt_perpetugas
    ]);
}
```